# GridView height is automatically increasing

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView control.And its pagesize is 10. I need to bind 23 records here. while binding the first 2 pages shows Rows with given height ,   but in the 3rd page  row height changes.  I mean it increases

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvInvidual" runat="server" Visible="False" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="MoGrid"       
            PagerStyle-CssClass="pgrM" ShowHeader="false" 
            onpageindexchanging="GvInvidual_PageIndexChanging" Height="285px" 
            Width="819px" PageSize="10" > 
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgrM"></PagerStyle> 
    <RowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" ForeColor="#000000"  Font-Size="14px"  CssClass="RowStyle"  />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4a70d0" ForeColor="#ffffff" Font-Size="15px" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#c0c0c0" ForeColor="#000000" Font-Size="14px"  CssClass="AlternateRowStyle"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

here is my css

```
.MoGrid .RowStyle
{
    height: 20px;
}
.MoGrid .AlternateRowStyle 
{
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: can you add snapshot for distortion in row height.
also check for data in data in that row, column data should contain spaces if data is large.

Comment: yes. i did check the data in the rows....data is not that much large....

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: can you please post snapshot of 3rd page in gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of your GridView is set to a fixed value (285px). The rows must adapt their height to add up to that total value. You may not notice it when the grid is filled with 10 rows but it becomes more apparent when fewer rows are displayed. If you remove `Height="285px"` from the GridView attributes, each row should keep its normal height.